# Is the Nodemailer SMTP server library compatible with UNIX sockets?

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, smtp-server

I have an SMTP server working that listens to a TCP port, but I want it to listen to traffic on a UNIX socket that my NGINX load balancer forwards the SMTP traffic onto. Is this possible, or will I have to stick to using a TCP port?